# Socket.IO adding connection when refreshing browser

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im adding Socket.IO on my NodeJS app (I'm a newbie btw) and when i refresh the webpage pressing F5 on Chrome a new socket is created according to my server log:

> user connected SWpG6Fv9mjmMoLZRAAAA
>   user disconnected SWpG6Fv9mjmMoLZRAAAA
>   user connected gvtxcnJR6sC4DW7CAAAB
>   user connected gvtxcnJR6sC4DW7CAAAB
>   user disconnected gvtxcnJR6sC4DW7CAAAB
>   user disconnected gvtxcnJR6sC4DW7CAAAB
>   user connected pWPjZbVV_-lnVL4RAAAC
>   user connected pWPjZbVV_-lnVL4RAAAC
>   user connected pWPjZbVV_-lnVL4RAAAC
>   user disconnected pWPjZbVV_-lnVL4RAAAC
>   user disconnected pWPjZbVV_-lnVL4RAAAC
>   user disconnected pWPjZbVV_-lnVL4RAAAC
>   user connected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user connected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user connected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user connected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user disconnected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user disconnected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user disconnected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user disconnected sP7lJaRrH6Hrevp7AAAD
>   user connected -86W-itTDwrsyeVGAAAE
>   user connected -86W-itTDwrsyeVGAAAE
>   user connected -86W-itTDwrsyeVGAAAE
>   user connected -86W-itTDwrsyeVGAAAE
>   user connected -86W-itTDwrsyeVGAAAE

Any ideas on why is happening this?

Here is my code:

**index.js:**

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const socket = require('socket.io')(http);

const opn = require('opn');

const login = require('./scripts/login.js');
const main = require('./scripts/main.js')(socket);
const init = require('./scripts/init.js');
const config = require('./scripts/config.js');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('==> Servidor iniciado -- Puerto 3000');
});

opn('http://localhost:3000');

app.use('/', main);
```

**main.js**

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const main = function (socket) {

    // Home page route.
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log('user connected ' + socket.id);
            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                console.log('user disconnected ' + socket.id);
            });
        });

        res.render('main', {
            page_name: 'main'
        });
    });

    return router;
};

module.exports = main;
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        console.log('connected');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't actually getting multiple connections, but rather you are adding more and more listeners for the `connection` event so you end up processing the same event multiple times (leading to the appearance of multiple connections).

When you put a socket.io `connect` event listener inside a route handler like this:

```
// Home page route.
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('user connected ' + socket.id);
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('user disconnected ' + socket.id);
        });
    });

    res.render('main', {
        page_name: 'main'
    });
});
```

Then, EVERY time that `/` route is hit, you add yet another duplicate listener for the `connection` event.  So, when one new socket.io connection happens, you have multiple listeners for it and thus you processing the same connection multiple times (creating confusing logging).

The solution is typically to move the socket.io listeners outside of any route handler so they are installed only once.  But, if you put them inside the route handler because of some other reason, then you will also have to solve that other issue too.  In any case, the socket.io listener has to be outside of any route handler so it is only installed once at server startup.

Perhaps like this:

```
"use strict";
const router = require('express').Router();

module.exports = function(io) {

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('user connected ' + socket.id);
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('user disconnected ' + socket.id);
        });
    });

    // Home page route.
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('main', {
            page_name: 'main'
        });
    });

    return router;
};
```

Note, you also had two variables in the same scope both named `socket`.  That's a bad practice as it blocks access to the higher scoped one and generally creates an opportunity for mistakes or confusion when working on the code.

Your higher level one should probably be named `io` so as not to confused with the `socket` parameter to the `connection` event and `io` is the usual convention when referring to the main socket.io server instance.

Comment: I absolutelly hate JS callbacks and listeners... thanks for your help

Comment: @Chico3001 - Well, being an event driven language, everything happens via a callback in Javascript, so you will need to learn and get comfortable with them or perhaps find a different type of programming environment.  This is really core to how Javascript in node.js and in a browser works.  Embrace it, learn it, become one with it rather than fight it.  Anyway, glad this solved your issue.